# Redirect HTTP upgrade to a websocket on another instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I use Node cluster, on each worker there's a running websocket server. Master has a HTTP server running.

On the Master HTTP server I want a HTTP Upgrade call implementation, that will connect the caller to a specific web socket.

Why? I want to be able to connect user to a correct websocket, but I want to do it through a single entry point being localhost:8000. Connecting to localhost:8000 might connect you to localhost:8001 seamlessly.

My idea was to call Upgrade with a parameter like:

```
wscat -c ws://localhost:8000/?id=5
```

This call should go to the Master, and master would forward this upgrade call and make connection with localhost:8005.

I thought I could simply forward the upgrade params to the worker with worker.send(), but this doesn't really work, objects I receive in the worker miss a lot of things, it's probably some basics of JS I don't know about.

Here's my naive implementation:

```
var http = require('http');
var cluster = require('cluster')
var ws = require('ws');

var NumberOfInstances = 5;

if (cluster.isMaster) {

    var forks = []
    for (var i=0; i < NumberOfInstances; i++) {
        forks.push(cluster.fork());
    }

    server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
        res.writeHead(200);
    }).listen(8000);

    server.on('upgrade', (request, socket, head) => {
        var params = new URL(`https://localhost:8000${request.url}`);
        var id = parseInt(params.searchParams.get('clusterId')) - 1;

        // How do I forward upgrade??
        forks[id].send({r: request, s: socket, h: head});
    })

} else {

    portStr = `800${cluster.worker.id}`;
    wss = new ws.WebSocketServer({
        port: portStr
    });

    wss.on('connection', (ws, request) => {
        console.log(`${cluster.worker.id} got connection.`);
    })

    process.on('message', masterMessage => {
        // This absolutely doesn't work. 
        wss.handleUpgrade(masterMessage.r, masterMessage.s, masterMessage.h, (ws) => {
            wss.emit('connection', ws, masterMessage.r);
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#workersendmessage-sendhandle-options-callback), you are required to send the socket handler as a second argument to the `worker.send` method.

So you should do this instead,

```
forks[id].send({ headers: request.headers, method: request.method, head: head }, socket); //socket is in second argument
```

and in your child `message` event handler, do this,

```
process.on('message', (request,socket) => {
    
    wss.handleUpgrade(request, socket, request.head, (ws) => {
        wss.emit('connection', ws, request);
    })
})
```

Look at [this](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#example-sending-a-socket-object) example to see how to pass socket object as an argument.